# How to share tool tips across webpages in ASP.Net Web forms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, tooltip

I am designing a web site with lots of co-related data entry forms and I want to give user tool tip for each text box entry. And lots of these text box entries repeats across pages. So I need some method where a collection of  tool tips can be accessed(Preferably stored in a XML file ) by clicking on a help icon besides each text box entry.

I don't want to store tool tips in back end DB and as it involves lots of overhead.

Is there a suitable method that I can follow to implement my requirement?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Are you just asking how to read an XML file in C#?  Did you try anything?

Comment: My requirement is to access common tool tips across pages instead of hard coding tool tips into each individual pages. I mentioned XML  because  I am not interested to use back end database. And I have not found anything good on google too

Comment: Well, reading from an XML file in C# is pretty easily found on Google.  What's your actual question?  Where specifically are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Create a User Control called ToolTips.ascx (or using the naming convention of your choice). The control would accept a key value, which would be used in the control to retrieve the corresponding value from your XML file.

In the page code behind, load the user control in the help icon `OnClick` event.